# Web Browser in an Irrlicht application?

Tags: c++, irrlicht

I'd like to know whether I can embed a web browser control into my Irrlicht (http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net) application.

A simple HTML renderer or maybe a trick to embed an Internet Explorer ActiveX control into my Irrlicht application is just OK.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated! :)

FYI: Irrlicht 1.6 on Windows platform with MSVC++ 2008 EE

note: sometimes I get better and faster responses in SO rather than in the community forum itself. ;D